# What do the typscript parameters between {} mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the following piece of typescript code I don't understand why the data parameter is between curly brackets and why it has a : followed by the same data object with a type specification. What does this mean?

```
addArrivingTruckSuggestions(state: ITruckState, { data }: { data: IOperationalTruck[] }) {
        state.arrivingTruckSuggestions = searchService.createTruckSuggestions(data);
    }
```

Comment: [Destructuring_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and its type.

Comment: `data` is a property on the second argument, and after the `:` is the specification of the object, that says, it has a property `data` with the type `array of IOperationalTruck`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function has two parameters, `state`, and an object containing `data`.

The `state` object has a type of `ITruckState`. Straight forward enough.

The next parameter must be an object, but the only property this function cares about is `data`. This is why there are curly braces around `data`, it is being destructured from the wrapper object that is passed in. The second set of curly braces is to define `data`s type. It is wrapped in curly braces because only the `data` property is given a type.

Comment: Great explanation! If i have to add: are you used to ES2015 "destructuring" syntax? If not, learning those in advance will help you to understand syntax like that.